# Prometheus Query Overall average under a time interval

Tags: prometheus, promql

How can I find the overall average of metrics over time interval ?

*avg(metric) = overall average value*
but

**avg_over_time(metrics[interval]) = averages value per label**

*avg( avg_over_time(metric[scrape interval]) )*  **won't be same as**(when the data is not continuous and denominator value is different) *avg(metric)* !!!!

Given a scenario, what will be the possible way to find the overall average over a time period.

Eg: Find the average response time now and Find the average response time(over all) of all the request triggered in last one hour.

The **number** will be helpful to notify a performance issue with latest upgrades.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to calculate the average a bit more manually:

```
    sum(sum_over_time(metric[interval]))
/
    sum(count_over_time(metric[interval]))
```

Note that this is for data in a gauge, you'd need a different approach for data from a counter or summary.

Comment: Thanks. Missed it.         My metrics are of type Summary, sum(sum_over_time(metric_sum[interval]))
/
    sum(sum_over_time(metric_count[interval])) !!!

Comment: For a summary it's `sum(rate(a_sum[interval])) / sum(rate(a_count[interval]))`. See https://www.robustperception.io/common-query-patterns-in-promql