# Aggregate data over time (by year/month/day) in prometheus

Tags: group-by, prometheus, promql

## Context

I am currently learning PromQL and I try to do an equivalent of the SQL "groupby" (with an aggregator like avg).

## Tests

I try a few steps toward the solution on [PromLens](https://demo.promlens.com) based on the [doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) and [this SoF solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175218/group-data-by-year-month-day-in-prometheus#).

I test my queries with the following base query:
`node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu='0', mode='user'}`.
It gives me this graph:
[image: base query]

The first query uses the `avg_over_time` to get the average value per month:

`avg_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu='0', mode='user'}[1y:4w])`

It gives me the following graph:
[image: avg over time]

It looks fine but the constant value of each month does not make any sense when checking the original query. In fact, the avg divide the sum_over_time by the count_over_time (like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859464/prometheus-query-overall-average-under-a-time-interval)). So, I tried to execute the count_over_time function and it only count the month of the year, which explains the results of avg_over_time.

Combining the query with the solution cited above does not bring interesting results too.

```
avg_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu='0', mode='user'}[1y:4w]) + ignoring(year, month, day) group_right
  count_values without() ("year", year(timestamp(
    count_values without() ("month", month(timestamp(
        avg_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu='0', mode='user'}[1y:4w])
    )))
  ))) * 0
```

It only labels the series:
[image: labelled]

Finally, I can try to execute a subquery to get a range vector of a value in each month, but it is still not the average value of a month.

`node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu='0', mode='user'}[1y:4w]`

## Question

Is it really possible to achieve what I want to do? I assume this is an essential feature but I do not know how to do this.
Thank you.